# saving data into binary file when dynamically allocated array is used

Tags: c, file, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, binaryfiles

I have data that I want saved into a file. After running the program for the second time (after writing the data i want) the data that was saved is read as random values (arbitrary numbers). I'm not sure if this is because of the dynamically allocated array I'm using or not. If someone can tell me why its not saving and printing the correct data?

This is a sample of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int length=4, width=4;

struct LandData
{
    int height;
};

struct LandData* WritingData()
{
    int i, j, op;
    FILE *land;

    struct LandData *arr = (struct LandData*)malloc(length* width* sizeof(struct LandData));

    if((land=fopen("file.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open File");
    }

    if(!(fread(arr,sizeof(struct LandData),1,land)))
    {
        printf("Error file is empty!\n");
            if((land = fopen("file.bin", "wb")) == NULL)
            {
            printf("Unable to open file!\n");
            exit(1);
            }else printf("Opened file successfully.\n");

            for (i = 0; i < length ; i++){
               for (j = 0; j < width; j++){
                  printf("choose height: ");
                  scanf("%d",&(arr + i*width + j)->height);
                  fwrite(arr, sizeof(struct LandData), 1, land);
                }
            }
            if(fclose(land)!=0)
            {
                perror("Error on file closing after writing");
                exit(2);
            }
            
    } 

    return(arr);
}

void DisplayingMap(struct LandData *arr)
{
    FILE* land;

    if((land=fopen("file.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open File");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n     ");
    for (int i=0 ; i<width; i++)
    printf("%d| ", i);
    printf("\n");

    while(fread(arr,sizeof(struct LandData),1,land))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
            printf(" %d| ", i);
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            printf(" %d ", (arr + i*width + j)->height);
            printf("\n");
        }

        if(fclose(land)!=0)
        {
        perror("Error on file closing after reading");
        exit(2);
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    struct LandData *arr = WritingData();
    DisplayingMap(arr);
   
}
```

Comment: Dynamic allocation is not the problem. The names of var and functions don't make it very clear of what you are trying to do. I suppose you want to 1: **dynamically generate** an array of structs, 2: **serialize** that array to a file, 3: **de-serialize** that file into an array and print its data. Is this correct?

Comment: There are many errors in your code and it is very mixed up. In the `WritingData` you open a file you never close. In `DisplayingMap` you read uninitialized data and also close a file even before you are done using it.

Comment: @DavidSais the first 2 parts yes but at the end I just want to read the array from the file (if that makes sense). when i run the program for the second time the numbers that i wrote are not being read which means they are not being saved in the first place

Comment: The data is being saved, but you are printing data of pointers that point to uninitialized data.

Comment: If you have noticed the first number is correct, but all the others are incorrect, then you should check my answer bellow. If that doesn't work, then the issue is something else.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to rewrite your code to make it more legible. The idea is to make functions with very specific tasks, this way code is not mixed everywhere. Bellow is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WIDTH 4
#define HEIGHT 4

typedef struct
{
    int data;
}LandData;

int fileExists(char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return 0;
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}

void fillArray(LandData *array)
{
    printf("Give me the data\n");
    for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row  < HEIGHT; row++)
        {
            printf("[%d, %d]: ", column, row);
            scanf("%d", &(array[row + column * HEIGHT].data));
        }
    }
}

void serializeArray(LandData *array, char *filename)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fwrite(array, sizeof(LandData), WIDTH * HEIGHT, file);
    
    fclose(file);
}

void printSerializedArray(char *filename)
{
    LandData array[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fread(array, sizeof(LandData), WIDTH * HEIGHT, file);
    
    for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row  < HEIGHT; row++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[row + column * HEIGHT].data);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (fileExists("file.bin"))
    {
        printSerializedArray("file.bin");
    }else
    {
        LandData array[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
        fillArray(array);
        serializeArray(array, "file.bin");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't use dynamic-allocated arrays (since its not necessary), but if you want to use dynamic arrays then simply replace `LandData array[WIDTH * HEIGHT];` with `LandData *array = malloc(sizeof(LandData) * WIDTH * HEIGHT);`.

Comment: I tried this and it prints "1" everywhere so I guess the issue is somewhere else

Comment: Was '1' the input you gave to the first item of the array?

Comment: yes its printing the first input i give to the array only

Comment: @David Sais - If (and that's probably the case) `file.bin` filled with wrong data from Mn Nm's attempt exists, your program doesn't produce the correct file and only prints the existing wrong content.